# Toggle keys inside processing code

Tags: toggle, processing

```java
if (keyPressed) {
  if (key == 'r') {
    }
  }
}

void keyReleased() {
  if (key == 'r') { 
    stroke(random(0,255), random(0,255), random(0,255));
    line(mouseX, mouseY, pmouseX, pmouseY);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create a function that allows the code to toggle random color depending on whether or not I press 'r'. Am I on the right path or is there an issue with the syntax? I have tried booleans, class types, and if statements.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what you're asking, but [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/input) is a tutorial on getting user input in Processing. You should also really try to [break your problem down into smaller steps](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and then take those steps on one at a time.

For example, here is a small example program that draws a random color when you press the `R` key:

```java
void draw(){}

void keyPressed(){
  if(key == 'r'){
   background(random(256), random(256), random(256)); 
  }
}
```

I suggest you start with a small program like this, and only focus on one small part of your problem at once. Then if you get stuck, you can post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with a specific technical question. Good luck.

Comment: I'm trying to get the code to toggle on and off . If I press the r key it turns into color mode where the line changes color then when I press it again it switches back to drawing a basic white line.

Comment: @DivinaSims Sounds like you could use a `boolean` variable for that. Toggle it in the `keyPressed()` function, then check it in the `draw()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I did understand what you're asking for. The following code swap between 2 colors when you press r or R (baseColor and a random one).

```
color currentColor;
color baseColor = color(0, 0, 0, 255);

void setup() {
    currentColor = baseColor;
    stroke(currentColor);
    size(600, 600);
}

void draw() {
    background(255, 255, 255, 255);
    line(width / 2, height / 2, mouseX, mouseY);
}

void keyReleased() {
    if(key == 'r' || key == 'R') { // key is case sensitive
        if(!(currentColor == baseColor))
            currentColor = baseColor;
        else
            currentColor = color(random(0, 255), random(0, 255), random(0, 255), random(0, 255)); // your color
        stroke(currentColor);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why didn't it worked with my code? Should I use two global variables when trying to toggle keys or does it only work with this example?

Comment: @DivinaSims It just draws a line from the center of the screen to the mouse position, swapping between baseColor and a random one. It's the main file so if you create a new Processing sketch and just copy-paste it should work, so you can examine the code and see what's going on.